# Стоит ли обособлять определения?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Стоит ли ставить запятую между определениями в этом предложении?

*Длинные волнистые темные волосы спадают на спину.*

Вроде бы определения неоднородные. Но не характеризуют ли они предмет с одной стороны?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я думаю, что определения являются неоднородными, то есть характеризующими предмет (волосы) с разных сторон: *длинные* — "протяженность" волос (антоним — короткие), *волнистые* — структуру (антоним — прямые), *темные* — цвет (антоним — светлые).
И я думаю, что запятые не нужны.

*Губы влажно блестели, зубы сверкали белизной, **длинные волнистые темные** волосы падали на плечи, ее кожа была цвета иранской земли, оливково-коричневая* (Джеймс Клавелл).
***Длинные волнистые тёмные** волосы струились по спине и груди, глаза были подведены чёрным, и в них читалась необъяснимая злоба на все живое* (Рик Нордсон).
*Её губы смеялись, а **длинные волнистые тёмные** волосы разлетались по плечам* (Валентина Полякова).

Для сравнения:
***Короткие прямые светлые** волосы и яркие голубые глаза Мэдисон без труда привлекали внимание* (Павел Андреев).

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)

**Дополнение**

> Если такие признаки объединены общим родовым понятием, подобные определения могут стать однородными: *Для туристской базы отведён **большой, каменный** дом* (объединяющий признак — ‘благоустроенный’).

Вот подходящий пример с обособлением:
*Отдаленно напоминаю **средиземноморский** тип: **длинные, волнистые, темные** волосы и глаза цвета кофе эспрессо* (Изабель Вульф).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Тоже склоняюсь к такому мнению. Ваши примеры очень помогли!

Comment: И вам поклон, Татьяна. Я дополнила свой ответ примером "наоборот".

Comment: Спасибо, поняла. И всё-таки в моём примере общего родового понятия нет, правильно?

Comment: В отрыве от контекста — нет.